# Google Token Api Invalid Request

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am sending Request like this

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code=4/4SYlDL_9PPvN2GWQIl3m8wzw4FknQsNVTS1C7s7rdIc&client_id=931376933291-jufjne4ihn9r8lnk2fdeib17fqhj6kks.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=y1LtscXK5aK4ZD0L3mJQv4mg&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com&grant_type=authorization_code

So getting Error like

{

```
"error": "invalid_request"
```

}

can anyone help me do this because I don't get it what is the wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got additional message when make the request
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}